# Calculating a discount java

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Detyra15
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        int percentage = 0;
        double releasevalue = 0;
        double discountedcost = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Shtyp cmimin e produktit te pare: ");
    double pr1 = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Shtyp cmimin e produktit te dyte: ");
    double pr2 = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Shtyp cmimin e produktit te trete: ");
    double pr3 = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Shtyp cmimin e produktit te katert: ");
    double pr4 = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Shtyp cmimin e produktit te peste: ");
    double pr5 = sc.nextDouble();

    double COST = (pr1 + pr2 + pr3 + pr4 + pr5);

    if(COST >= 20 && COST < 60)
    {
        percentage = 10;
        releasevalue = (COST*(10.0/100.0));
    }
    else if(COST >= 60 && COST < 100)
    {
        percentage = 20;
        releasevalue = (COST*(20.0/100.0));
    }
    else{
        percentage = 30;
        releasevalue = (COST*(30.0/100.0));
    }

    discountedcost = COST - releasevalue;
```

This its the code that i've done, but the problem is at the PERCENTAGE, i need to use percentage as a constant value? If i put at the int percentage = 0; final than i can't do at the if else percentage 10 20 30.... how to do that? I need the percentage only 10% 20% 30%...

UPDATE=== I'VE DONE!!!
Thankyou

Comment: Nay, alas, you have to solve your homework on your own. We all had to go through that. :)

Comment: Share your code and we can help you with some guidelines. Nobody here will do the homework for you.

Comment: you could provide the code you have already written and point out where you are struggeling. This would make it more likely that you´ll be getting an answer.

Comment: You'll do better here if you post code and ask questions about specific difficulties.  This isn't a "haz the codez" site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a think about how you can code simple mathematics into your program, I will start you off with an example.

```
if (productCost >= 20 && productCost < 60)
{
    discount = 0.9;
}
```

What this does is check if the cost of the product lies between 20 and 60 and if it does it sets the discount to 0.9. This is 0.9 because when you multiply this by the total cost, it will take 10% off.

Use this as a guideline and try and figure out the other things yourself, you won't learn without trying at least.

Comment: Maybe good advice, but a bad example.  Magic numbers everywhere.

Comment: Yes, understandable, but in an example the magic numbers are fine. If I was to use variables for everything, they may not understand what was going on. Also, magic numbers aren't necessarily bad if you know they are going to be constant (notably 0 and 1), although final could be used in these cases.

Comment: They are bad if they're constant.  Names will give you context and a chance to understand what it means and where's it from that a magic number can never match.

Comment: @duffymo did you not read what I just explained?